# Fitts's Law Favourite Tags Script

Tags: script

[image: A Screenshot]

For people like myself who fail at hitting things or just want to [hit them faster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_Law) (i use this in combination with the [delete button removal script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2540/remove-delete-favourite-tag-buttons-script))

Sorry to not provide a file for download but i am sure you will manage somehow, adjust includes as needed:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Fitts's Law Favourite Tags
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @include        *stackoverflow.com*
// ==/UserScript==

(function ()
{
    var cancelWaiting = false;
    jq_wait();

    function jq_wait()
    {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined')
        {
            window.setTimeout(jq_wait, 100);
        } else
        {
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;
            window.setTimeout(function () { cancelWaiting = true; }, 5000);
            $(document).ready(favs_wait);
        }
    }

    function favs_wait()
    {
        var items = $("#interestingTags .post-tag");
        if (items.length == 0)
        {
            if (cancelWaiting) return;
            window.setTimeout(favs_wait, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            items.css("padding", "5px 10px");
        }
})();
```